# How to handle duplicate column names while defining schema in KSQL

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform, ksqldb

How to handle duplicate column names while defining schema. In the below code trying to create duplicate columns for `SOURCES` and alias with  `SOURCES_ARRAY`. Getting errors as we cannot alias columns name. Any help would be appreciated.

```
create stream example
(with topic='example_topic',value_format='JSON')
(changeType varchar,
domain varchar,
id varchar,
payload struct<id varchar,
                domain varchar,
                rootState varchar, 
                sources array<struct< 
                        source varchar,
                        domain varchar, ETC >>>,
payload struct<sources array<varchar) as sources_array;
```

Comment: What's the exact error? What you've posted has some syntax issues around `struct<sources array<varchar)`. You've already named the columns, so why do you need `as` aliasing at creation time? I think your error is on the two `payload` Structs

Comment: @OneCricketeer basically I want to create two columns with name sources and trying to alias one of them. Is it possible to create while defining schema?

Comment: You only would use `as` during a select, not a create, but you need to fix the syntax first before a create will work. You can't rename JSON keys during stream creation as it needs to parse by those names

Comment: Besides that, having two top level `payload` fields is invalid JSON to begin with. Can you please edit your question to show what you're trying to parse?